# How to convert military time integer to standard time string

Tags: java

So I'm trying to write a program that tells a user what bus they can take to get to their class. I have one issue at the moment: I want to have the user pass an int to compare with an ArrayList of int values to tell them if they can catch that bus.

However, I'd like to convert the output to a 12-hour type string but I can't figure out an effective way to do it! Here's my code so far.

```
package bus;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
public class busSchedule {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int classTime = 0;
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What time do you have to be in class?: ");
        classTime = scnr.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < AB.toCampus.size() - 1; ++i){
            if(classTime > AB.toCampus.get(i)){
                String timeString = Integer.toString(AB.toCampus.get(i));
                DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm aa");
                String newTime = f2.format(timeString).toLowerCase();
                System.out.println("You can take the " + AB.line + " line at " + newTime + " to get to class.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I also have the class `AB` which is the name of the line. It follows:

```
package bus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AB {
    static String line = "A-B";
    static ArrayList<Integer> toCampus = new ArrayList<Integer>(
            Arrays.asList(623, 1234, 1734, 2100)
            );

}
```

The way it is, the output only prints 4:00 pm over and over.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply parse the military time to a time class and then format it to your desired output, for example...

```
ArrayList<Integer> toCampus = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(623, 1234, 1734, 2100)
);

for (int time : toCampus) {
    String value = String.format("%04d", time);
    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm"));
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a").format(lt));
}
```

Which outputs

```
06:23 AM
12:34 PM
05:34 PM
09:00 PM
```

Now, because your data is actually sorted, you can use `Collections.binarySearch` to find matches, for example...

```
ArrayList<Integer> toCampus = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(623, 1234, 1734, 2100)
);

Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("What time do you have to be in class?: ");
int classTime = scnr.nextInt();

int index = Collections.binarySearch(toCampus, classTime);
System.out.println(index);
if (index < 0) {
    index = Math.abs(index) - 1;
}

if (index > 0 && index <= toCampus.size()) {
    int time = toCampus.get(index - 1);
    String value = String.format("%04d", time);
    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm"));
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a").format(lt));
} else {
    System.out.println("Go back to bed");
}
```

When `Collections.binarySearch` can't find a match, it will return *"-(insertion point) - 1"*, this tells us where out item would have appeared, had it been in the `List`.

This allows us to make some decisions about which value in the list is most appropriate.

For example, if we enter `630`, the `binarySearch` will return `-2`, add `1` for the offset, which gives us `-1`, convert it to a positive number and that would `1`.  Now, obviously the element at `1` is `1234`, but if we take the previous one, it returns `623`!

Comment: I like that `else` clause! ;)

Comment: @Mrt Reminds me of my good old uni days, "Opps, missed that class, back to bed" :P

Comment: I don't want to ask too much, but suppose I wanted to check if the student could make it to his/her class on time (maybe in 7 minutes) based on a comparison between the time the bus arrived on campus(I made a new ArrayList called atCampus) and the time their class starts. Could I make this code work?

Comment: Basically the time conversation code, won't care.  The `binarySearch` would need some work, but the basic principle would be the same, you take what they enter and determine if the time before is greater then 7 minutes difference or not, if not, you need to move back another element.  Of course, you could just subtract 7 minutes of the time the user gives you and give that try